# How to recover files from a VDI?

Tags: virtualbox, centos-7, file-recovery

I've tried a lot of different things already. For a synopsis of what caused the problem, please see [this unanswered question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/392530/centos-7-wont-start-after-recent-update) on Unix/Linux stack exchange. Basically, I'm on a Windows 10 host and I have an unbootable CentOS 7 VM on Virtual Box. I need to know how to recover files from my unbootable VDI.

I've read [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/236205/how-do-i-recover-files-from-a-corrupt-vdi-file) (and many others), for which creating a new profile for the VM didn't fix it. I'm also unsure how a rescue disk would fix it--very unclear instructions. I've tried several different discontinued softwares. I've also tried "mounting" the virtual disk through VirtualBox in a brand new CentOS installation (that just...didn't work; it thought I wanted to boot from the old one).

I feel like I've exhausted everything I can find on the Internet, so I might as well raise a duplicate question.

Comment: Mount the disk in a new CentOS installation and then press F12 after starting the VM. That allows you to select which disk to boot from.

Comment: Could you be more specific on how it gets mounted?

Comment: See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105430/mounting-another-vms-vdi-in-virtualbox)

Comment: Okay good, that's what I was doing. Regardless, it didn't work. It took forever to get past the loading bar for CentOS, and then dumped me at an "emergency mode".

Comment: Are you sure you selected the right disk to boot from? If it doesn't work you can also boot from a DVD iso instead.

Comment: Alright wow, I can actually see my file directory again after booting from the rescue option from the DVD iso. How do I get the files out?

Comment: Do you want to copy them to your real disk or to another virtual machine?

Comment: They're just going to another VM, but I can work with either solution.

Comment: In that case go with first solution I mentioned. Mount your old disk in the new VM.

Comment: It still didn't work. Mounting the old vdi in the new VM prevents it from booting. (Yes, I'm running the right disk.)

Comment: Then boot from DVD again, after mounting the second disk.

Comment: It didn't like when I tried to mount both, it spat out some errors too quick to read. It would ask me to select an option and then prompt me over and over (mount it, read only, shell, quit).

Comment: Fine, in that case you can try to copy the files over the network. In the networking settings set both VMs to "bridged mode". Then boot them both up, check their ip addresses with `ifconfig` and then use a [tarpipe](http://toast.djw.org.uk/tarpipe.html) (replace `otherhost` with the ip of the other VM). Just make sure you cd to the right folder in both VMs first.

Comment: It told me the network was unreachable, could you clarify on the bridged mode settings so I know if I have it right? Actually, it seems I don't have Internet connectivity in booting from the DVD.

Comment: Where did it tell you that it was unreachable? In CentOS after booting up?
 The bridged mode setting is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaRwa.png). Alternatively you can also try "internal network".

Comment: It says unreachable inside the shell of the VM where I'm booting from the DVD iso with the old disk. I know I'm not getting connectivity in general on that VM because I can't ssh to a server I know. Also, I just tried it again with the settings you graciously provided in that picture. (Thank you so much for trying to help me this much)

Comment: That makes no sense. You should be able to get a connection. Maybe try a different DVD. I know that Linux Mint and Ubuntu live DVDs work fine in VirtualBox.

Comment: Does it not matter if I use an Ubuntu iso to rescue a CentOS machine? (I have it downloading, but it'll be a while)

Comment: Ubuntu wouldn't give me permissions into my own directories (from the old disk), nor did sudo recognize the "cd" command, so I'm trying Linux Mint

Comment: Try sudo bash instead of sudo cd. or just su

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65746/discussion-between-peri461-and-spiderpig).

Comment: @SpiderPig, for what it's worth, if you write up an answer, I'll mark it accepted. I appreciated your help back then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mount the disk in a new CentOS installation and then press F12 after starting the VM. That allows you to select which disk to boot from.
If it doesn't work with CentOS try a different distribution. I know that Linux Mint and Ubuntu live DVDs work fine in VirtualBox.